# Best way to sync windows services between two servers?

Tags: windows, command-line, sync, windows-server-2012

I'm wanting to bring an older company server back in the deployment loop and was looking at the Robocopy cmd. So of course it can easily sync files and all that good stuff, but I'm wondering if Robocopy can sync Windows Services too. Basically I am wanting to use Robocopy to copy all Windows Services with their credential information from our active deployment server to the older one. And can Robocopy update or sync directory permission structures?

Thank you!

Comment: Services are (can be) programs with settings. So you are trying to move configured applications.  This does not seem very likely to accomplish.

Comment: @John Gotcha! I'm only exploring options so if Robocopy doesn't seem like the best method, I'll go off to the next option I find. Couldn't find anything on how to do it with Robocopy so I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am wanting to use Robocopy to copy all Windows Services with their credential information from our active deployment server to the older one.

Services are settings in program applications.  The new server will most likely have new versions of these applications. If you could copy the application to the new place (not really possible), it would not likely work.

Credentials are application dependent and some credentials can be exported to the very same application in a new system (Chrome, Edge) but that does not typically apply to program settings.

This is a long answer for:  Not really practical.  Set up the new server with new settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for the longer explanation. I'm still learning quite a bit so sorry if its a newbie question.

Comment: Would you happen to know some other way to achieve this? Any type of built in software or third party software? Or does your answer apply to Robocopy and all other ways?

Comment: Not really. There can be many differences between versions of software and I do not know of any software that can move old settings to new settings in the same or different places.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks again!